# Twitter Bootstrap Navigation Bar - Right Alignment Control

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap (v2.1.1) and trying to customise the position/alignment of the various navigation bar elements.

Here's a jsFiddle showing a simplified version of the navigation bar:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/nhnH6/2/

I would like the search input form to appear aligned right but before the last "Dropdown 2". I tried changing:

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-left" action="">
```

to:

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-right" action="">
```

but that makes the search input form the last navigation bar item, not the 2nd last which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Is this possible to have the search input form 2nd last aligned to the right?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the 2 right-aligned elements in a div.

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="pull-right"> ... </div>
```

Here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nhnH6/3/

Comment: it seems like the Bootstrap library has changed since. i recommend re-create the example with a new fiddle. cheers.